# Unity game extecutable sometimes takes longer to launch, and Unity splash logo doesn't show

Tags: unity, c#, splash-screen

In the exported build of my game (which uses Unity 2020.3.15f2), I notice that sometimes the game's executable launches immediately, correctly fading in and out the built-in Unity logo on the splash screen (which is set via Project Settings to take 3s).

[image]

Other times, however, it takes a few seconds to launch and the built-in Unity logo does not seem to show on the splash screen. (We know that we are nonetheless on the splash screen, however, since I have it colored red for debugging purposes).

[image]

[Here](https://youtu.be/u_wcX3S2gXc) is some video showing the phenomenon.

There appears to be no pattern to when it boots correctly versus incorrectly (seems to be about 50-50). It makes no difference whether I have the Untity editor running or not in another window.

My hardware specs are good. The executable is only 627 KB. Further, I have made sure I am not doing any performance intensive process on boot. I even scaled back my pooling system from instantiating 10,000 objects on boot to instantiating zero.

I would like the experience of launching my executable to be consistent, always fading the built-in Unity logo in and out.

**Does anyone have advice on diagnosing, troubleshooting, or solving this issue?**

Comment: Have you tried hooking the Unity profiler into the built game to see if any particular spikes show up in its metrics?

Comment: @DMGregory I have not. Never done that. Let me try and will update question with results.

Comment: When a build is connected to the profiler, the profiler doesn't seem to capture anything unless you run the executable, then go back into profiler and toggle the record button. I can't seem to profile the interval between running the exe then toggling the record button in the profiler to start capturing...